# reStructuredText in Python functions not displaying in Robot Framework hub

Tags: python, robotframework

My sample Python module for robotframework looks like this.

```
ROBOT_LIBRARY_DOC_FORMAT = 'reST'

def foo (a, b):
    """Produces bar.

    :param ``a``: this is a.
    :param ``b``: this is b.
    """
```

But then using the rfhub Web app to view in browser, param a and b are smashed onto one line, and it looks like it is coming out as the wiki style. Is reST supported in rfhub? See below screen shot.

```
user@ubuntu-01:~$ python -m rfhub ./test-project/testcases
tornado web server running on http://127.0.0.1:7070
```

[rfhub_example_helloworld](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DpLpT.png)

Answer (score 0):

My suspicion at this point is that it is simply not supported by robotframework hub.

To doublecheck it, I did this:

user@ubuntu-01:~$ python -m robot.libdoc ./test-project/testcases/HelloWorld.py testdoc.html

where the HelloWorld.py was:

```
ROBOT_LIBRARY_DOC_FORMAT = 'reST' 

def foo(a, b): 
    """Produces bar. 

    :param ``a``: this is a. 
    :param ``b``: this is b. 
    """ 
    return "bar" 

def foo2(a, b): 
    """Also produces bar. 

    :a: this is a. 
    :b: this is b. 
    """ 
    return "bar"
```

Above produces this output in my browser:

[libdoc_output_restructuredtext](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mgtj0.png)

Which shows the fields are broken onto separate lines as I expect for reStructuredText. If I comment out the ROBOT_LIBRARY_DOC_FORMAT line, that no longer works. I'll add a similar screenshot to my original question showing the issue in robotframework hub.